# Replacement for SkuDetailsParams in Billing 6.0.1

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I recently updated my Android app to use Billing Library version 6.0.1, and I noticed that SkuDetailsParams class is deprecated. I'm trying to find the new replacement or alternative for SkuDetailsParams in this version.

Previously, I used SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder() to set the parameters for querying SKU details. What is the recommended way to achieve the same functionality in Billing 6.0.1
before the update I used:

```
SkuDetailsParams skuDetailsParams = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        .setSkusList(Collections.singletonList(productId))
        .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
        .build();

mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParams, (billingResult, skuDetailsList) -> {
    // Query response handling logic...
});
```

any guidance on how to replace SkuDetailsParams in Billing 6.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

You must now use `QueryProductDetailsParams`, `QueryProductDetailsParams.Product`, and `queryProductDetailsAsync`.
Also consider the case of an [outdated Play Services](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#isFeatureSupported(java.lang.String)) version on the user's device, in such case, you need to fallback to deprecated methods.

Check out this [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate-gpblv6) from v4-5 to v6, it has all you need to know.